# Rails - Saving Mail Attachment in a Postgres DB, results in PGError: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Has anyone seen this error before?

> PGError: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0

I'm trying to save an incoming mail attachment(s), of any file type to the database for processing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of column are you saving your data to? If the attachment could be of any type, you need a **bytea** column to ensure that the data is simply passed through as a blob (binary "large" object). As mentioned in other answers, that error indicates that some data sent to PostgreSQL that was tagged as being text in UTF-8 encoding was invalid.

I'd recommend you store email attachments as binary along with their MIME content-type header. The Content-Type header should include the character encoding needed to convert the binary content to text for attachments where that makes sense: e.g. "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1".

If you want the decoded text available in the database, you can have the application decode it and store the textual content, maybe having an extra column for the decoded version. That's useful if you want to use PostgreSQL's full-text indexing on email attachments, for example. However, if you just want to store them in the database for later retrieval as-is, just store them as binary and leave worrying about text encoding to the application.

Answer (score 0):

The 0xa0 is a non-breaking space, possibly latin1 encoding. In Python I'd use str.decode() and str.encode() to change it from its current encoding to the target encoding, here 'utf8'. But I don't know how you'd go about it in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Rails, but when PG gives this error message it means that :

- the connection between postgres and your Rails client is correctly configured to use utf-8 encoding, meaning that all text data going between the client and postgres must be encoed in utf-8
- and your Rails client erroneously sent some data encoded in another encoding (most probably latin-1 or ISO-8859) : therefore postgres rejects it

You must look into your client code where the data is inserted into the database, probably you try to insert a non-unicode string or there is some improper transcoding taking place.